# How to externally set the form state of a react final form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have a use case where I want to externally set the form state of a react final form.

By form state I mean, the following

1. errors
2. pristine
3. dirty
4. submitted ...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try to create a custom [mutator](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/Mutator) in which you can change the [mutableState](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/MutableState).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I manage state outside of React Final Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150754/how-do-i-manage-state-outside-of-react-final-form)

Comment: Did you managed to do it? I need to set errors object outside form.